# Passing hidden value php

Tags: php, html

HTML page

```
<form name='form' action='procces.php' method='POST'>
<input name='filename' type='hidden' value='myfile.rar'/>
<input name='filesize' type='hidden' value='23MB'/>
<input name='id' type='hidden' value='1.1.1.1'/>
<input type='submit' value='Send'/>
```

**procces.php**

```
<?php
$filename = $_POST['filename'];
$filesize = $_POST['filesize'];
$id = $_POST['id'];

echo "<form name='form' action=procces.php' method='POST'>
<input name='filename' type='hidden' value='".$filename."'/>
<input name='filesize' type='hidden' value='".$filesize."'/>
<input name='id' type='hidden' value='".$id."'/>
</from>";
?>
```

> - Notice: Undefined index: filename in    C:\xampp\htdocs\learning\procces.php on line 2
> - Notice: Undefined index: filename in C:\xampp\htdocs\learning\procces.php on line 3
> - Notice: Undefined index: filename in C:\xampp\htdocs\learning\procces.php on line 4

can help me to fix this? thanks..

Comment: There's a typo in the last line! from---> form

Comment: Fix the typo as pointed out above, and fix the form declaration at action. You're missing the opening quotation

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access `$_POST` ed values before form gets posted.

Hence the error.

Add a condition, get values only after form is posted.

But, first initialize the three variables to blank.

In case, you use it in later script, they should not show undefined variable errors.

```
$filename = '';
$filesize = '';
$id = '';
if (isset($_POST)) {
  $filename = $_POST['filename'];
  $filesize = $_POST['filesize'];
  $id = $_POST['id'];
}
```

Comment: Notice: Undefined index on line 6, 7, 8

Answer (score 0):

You cannot just assign the variables. You need to check if the `POST` variable exists. And they do not exist when the page has just been loaded and are created when a form is submitted.

Change this:

```
$filename = $_POST['filename'];
$filesize = $_POST['filesize'];
$id = $_POST['id'];
```

to this:

```
 if(isset($_POST['filename'])){
       $filename = $_POST['filename'];
    }
    if(isset($_POST['filesize'])){
       $filesize = $_POST['filesize'];
    }
    if(isset($_POST['id'])){
       $id = $_POST['id'];
    }
```